# Mock objects with spring aspect

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-aop, easymock

I have a test class:

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class) 
public class TestClass{

@TestSubject
private AdDataCollector collector = new DefaultAdDataCollector();
...

@Test
public void check() {
    .. some logic ...

    expect().andReturn();
    expect().andReturn();
    replay(...);
    Map<,> result = collector.collect(...);
    verify(...);
    assertTrue(...)
}
```

And such aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class SafeUriInterceptor {

@Autowired
private UriConverterUtil uriConverterUtil;

@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(SafeUrl) && args(param)")
public void proceedMethodWithSafeUrl(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String param) throws Throwable {
    String encodedValue = uriConverterUtil.encodeUriString(param);
    joinPoint.proceed(new Object[] { encodedValue });
}

@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(SafeUrl) && args(uriList)")
public void proceedMethodWithSafeUrlList(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, List<String> uriList) throws Throwable {
    List<String> encodedUriStrList = uriList != null
            ? uriList.stream().map(uriConverterUtil::encodeUriString).collect(Collectors.toList())
            : null;
    joinPoint.proceed(new Object[] { encodedUriStrList });
}
}
```

In test class inside `value.collect(...)` this aspect performs action. This method does many things and it needs safe url, therefore it uses aspect. In short, idea of method is:

```
public Map<,> collect() {
    Map<String,Apple> map = new HashMap<>();
    ...
    String unsafeUrl = "http://";
    apple.setValue(unsafeUrl);
    map.put(key, apple);
      ...

}
```

On method `apple.setValue(unsafeUrl)` aspect is executed (I do not entirely understand why it is called in test).
And I get NullPointerException, because of `UriConverterUtil` is null. 
I tried to mock `UriConverterUtil`, but this doesn't help. Object I mocked and object inside aspect `SafeUriInterceptor` are different objects. And I still get NullPointerException.

What can I do to just call method inside test without aspect? Or how can I mock `UriConverterUtil` inside aspect `SafeUriInterceptor`?  Or is there another solution?

It's my maven dependency, aspectj-maven-plugin

```
<plugins>
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                        <groupId>...</groupId>
                        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                    </weaveDependency>
                </weaveDependencies>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>...</groupId>
                        <artifactId>...</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           
</plugins>
```

**Possible solution**

So one solution I can guess is to check: if `uriConverterUtil`is  null. It will be null in all tests. And if it null I can execute method without uri modifications.

Comment: Question needs more information: what is `value.collect`, how it gets autowired, why is it autowired at all. I would expect that there is no need to test this component integration with AOP aspect, it rather should have "safe URI" passed as input.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I've edited my post

Comment: The question with all its snippets and "..." omissions is a bit incoherent. I do not understand the problem. I cannot even compile the code to see what it does. So please help me help you by providing a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A GitHub link would be fine.

Comment: What is your aspect strategy? Why do you even need the autowired collector - can't you simply create it just for the test?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, sorry, I don't autowire collector, I create object for test, it was a mistake. Aspect strategy is to work when `setValue` method was called

Comment: @Ales, do you weave spring AOP during compile time then? Otherwise, if you manually create the component, it wouldn't be a subject to AOP proxies.